# Using a ** wildcard in an F# project causes Visual Studio to refuse to load the project

Tags: visual-studio, f#, msbuild, project-structure

I've got an F# project with several additional files stored in many nested folders, creating a complex folder structure. The compiler doesn't need to know about them: all I need to do is to have them copied into the output directory at the end of the build process.

I tried adding my files using the ** wildcard:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <FilesToCopyToOutput Include="additionalData\**\*.*"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

It works fine when running MSBuild manually from PowerShell. However, when I attempt to open my project in Visual Studio (v. 2015), I get the following error message:

> Cannot open F# project . This project uses
>   wildcards in the item specification. Wildcards in F# projects are not
>   currently supported.

Similarly, a C# project with the wildcards works just fine. I guess this has something to do with the fact that the order of files in an F# project matters and using the wildcards causes a problem if a user wants to reorder the files.

However, I'm wondering if there's anything that can be done in my particular case: I don't care if the files are available in VS or not: I just want them to be copied to the output folder.

Comment: Upgrade to a current Visual Studio version. It's not just that VS 2015 is 3 years old, the F# compiler and infrastructure are *very* different with a *huge* amount of improvements. Compared to Visual Studio 2017 15.9, VS 2015 seemed little better than Notepad

Comment: Oh boy, I wish I could, but it's up to my company to use VS 2015, not VS 2017 ;).

Comment: VS 2017 Community Edition is free and functionally equivalent to VS Pro. In any case, it's the build system that complains. You *could* install fresh SDKs and F# versions, but that would still mean you'd be working with two different versions. You could use Visual Studio Code as the IDE

Comment: BTW the *F#* way would be to use a [FAKE](https://fake.build/) build script to build the projects and copy the data, with [Paket](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/) as the package manager.

Comment: Sure, understood. But the thing is: I can't change the tech stack, as it would take too much effort in the company to do so. Are there any walkarounds for the limitation that work with 2015 ?

Comment: @AlojzyLeszcz I'm quite certain I remember we were importing a separate *.proj file for these sorts of extra build steps? It was good enough to fool VS2013 ;)

Comment: @AlojzyLeszcz where did you find `FilesToCopyToOutput` ? It's not an MSBuild task and *shouldn't* be affected by any of the compilers MSBuild calls. Is it your own task perhaps, one that calls an F# script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using a ** wildcard in an F# project causes Visual Studio to refuse to load the project

Indeed, Visual Studio 2017 is a good choose. I have test the `**` wildcard in the Visual Studio 2015 and 2017, it works fine in the Visual Studio 2017 but not in the Visual Studio 2015, got the same error as you.

Since you could not change the tech stack to use Visual Studio 2017, I would like provide a workaround for this issue, you can check if it works for you.

Since you do not care if the files are available in VS or not, you just want them to be copied to the output folder, you can use a power shell script to copy the `additionalData` folder to the output folder, like:

```
Copy-Item -Path "ThePathForAdditionalData\additionalData" -Destination "ThePathForProject\bin\Debug" -recurse -Force
```

Then execute this power shell script with MSBuild task after build:

```
<Target Name="CopyMyFiles" AfterTargets="Build">
  <Message Text="Copying files..."/>
  <Exec Command="C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NonInteractive -executionpolicy Unrestricted -command &quot;&amp; { .\YourCopyFiles.ps1 } &quot;" ></Exec>
</Target>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `FilesToCopyToOutput` is the name you gave to an item collection, and the question is how to stop the old F# compiler from thinking it should handle it?

I suspect what you want to do though is to treat an entire folder as [content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items?view=vs-2015#content) items and copy them to the output folder :

```
<Content Include="additionalData\**\*.*">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

**Copy Task**

If you want to copy items with an MSBuild task you can use [Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/copy-task?view=vs-2015). You should be able to write :

```
<ItemGroup>
    <MyAdditionalData Include="additionalData\**\*.*" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="CopyFiles">  
    <Copy  
        SourceFiles="@(MyAdditionalData)"  
        DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)"  
    />  
</Target>
```

The `Include` attribute [allows selecting multiple files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-items?view=vs-2017) that can be used as arguments to a task. `Exclude` is used to exclude files. You can specify a `Condition` attribute too, eg to run the task only for Release or Debug configuration.  `$(OutputPath)` is one of the [MSBuild properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2017) that can be used in paths.

[How to: Exclude Files from the Build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-exclude-files-from-the-build?view=vs-2015) shows how you can combine all those attributes to process specific items in a directory, eg:

```
<JPGFile  
    Include="Images\**\*.jpg"  
    Exclude = "Images\**\Version2\*.jpg"/>
```

This will include all files in the `Images` directory except those in `Version2`

**Using Post-build events**

Most people though *didn't* use MSBuild until the latest simplified format. 
The most common way to copy files after build is to use a [post-build event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-build-events-csharp?view=vs-2017) from the project's property pages, eg :

```
xcopy $(ProjectDir)additionalData\*.* $(TargetDir) /s /e
```

`$(ProjectDir)` and `$(TargetDir)` are replacement macros that point to the projects' folder and output folder. The list of all macros is available in [Pre-build Event/Post-build Event Command Line Dialog Box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/pre-build-event-post-build-event-command-line-dialog-box?view=vs-2017).